# How to view hierarchical package structure in Eclipse package explorer

Tags: eclipse, package, hierarchy, package-explorer

OK here's what I would like: in the Eclipse package explorer, I see the following: (dot represents a clickable arrow that I can use to expand the folder)

- PROJECT

  - Source Folder

    - Package

        Class

      Package.SubPackage

        Foo

        Bar

      Package.OtherSubPackage

      Package.OtherSubPackage.VerySubPackage

      OtherPackage

        Foobar

      OtherPackage.SubPackage

        Baz

Long story short, I want to have many packages, each with many subpackages, in a source folder (and several source folders, so making more won't solve the problem)--so on the order of a couple hundred packages per source folder--ten to twenty packages each with fifteen subpackages. Therefore, I want the hierarchy to look like this:

- PROJECT

  - Source Folder

    - Package

        Class
      - Package.SubPackage

          Foo

          Bar

        Package.OtherSubPackage

        - Package.OtherSubPackage.VerySubPackage

    - OtherPackage

        Foobar
      - OtherPackage.SubPackage

          Baz

so I can open or close a package and see a list of subpackages instead of having package and subpackage all at the same level in the hierarchy--which again makes far too many packages simultaneously displayed. Note this is *not* a question about filesystem; the file system works fine as far as I can tell--it is only a question about the *visual display* in the Eclipse package explorer.

So: is there a way to add levels to the hierarchy? Thanks!! (Eclipse Helios on OS X 10.6)

Answer (score 811, accepted):

Package Explorer / View Menu / Package Presentation... / Hierarchical

The "View Menu" can be opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, or the small arrow-down icon in the top-right corner of the Package Explorer.

Comment: anybody knows how I get the "Folder Presentation" - "Grouped" option back? On my laptop it's not there :-{
(purpose: make groupo packages that contain only one subpackage)
Remark: just saw that i have "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" on my laptop whilst having "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers." on my desktop.

Comment: Yeah, on my Eclipse Indigo at work I have a button on the Package Explorer for this, but not on my fresh Indigo install at home. Wtf? Thanks for the CTRL+F10 trick, it saved the day!

Comment: Folder Presentation applies to JavaScript Source Folders.

Comment: You can see them grouped alright but still need to assign/remove new sub-packages to/from groups by renaming them with the right prefix. No drag&drop support.

Comment: why isn't this the default?

Comment: This option doesn't appear in the view menu on my installation of Eclipse (Luna 4.4.2), though it does appear in the documentation.  That's odd (maybe a bug?).

Comment: Note that the nested projects feature works in the Java EE perspective with the project explorer, but does not appear in the Java perspective with the package explorer. Also, if you have some working sets, then can cause havoc with the feature - making projects vanish in weird ways.

Comment: The View Menu is also accessible via Window > Navigation

Comment: Also see related question about the default value for this setting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836634/why-is-hierarchical-package-presentation-in-eclipse-package-explorer-not-the-def

Comment: This solution is still working on eclipse latest version

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do a combination of both oO - have the top 2 levels flat and then hierarchical -or maybe top2 levels flat one level hierarchical and then inside flat again sound most convenient

Answer (score 44):

Here is representation of screen eclipse to make hierarachical.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate this answer, as the screenshot helped me find what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: Not at all :) @cfnerd

Answer (score 18):

For Eclipse in **Macbook** it is just 2 click process:

- Click on view menu (3 dot symbol) in package explorer -> hover over package presentation -> Click on Hierarchical

[image]