# Importing a JAVA package doesn't exist

Tags: java, class, package, bluej

I am having a problem with a Java Class which keeps saying me the package I am trying to import doesn't exist but as you can see the package exist. The package name is `SecuGen` and it exist in the folder.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean 'exist' instead of 'exit'?

Comment: Have you successfully imported this package into other classes? If not, maybe the uppercase is the problem, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534302/why-should-java-package-name-be-lowercase)

Comment: I tried lowercase still got the same problem, unfortunately

Comment: if you are using _Eclipse_ then try with _refresh_ and _clean build_.

Comment: May [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117237/why-is-my-eclipse-java-package-being-treated-as-a-folder) helps you?

Comment: What does say the package exists? Is it the IDE you're using or the Java compiler? If it is the IDE did you set the source path correctly? If it is the compiler how do you call it? You are also only showing us the directory `SecuGen` exists, what about the subdirectories?

Comment: I fixed it , I don't  really know what I did, but it seems to work know

Answer (score 1):

check your classpath in your IDE.
do a clean and build