# Is there a way to nest packages in Eclipse's Package Explorer?

Tags: eclipse

I've been searching high and low for an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you want a hierarchical presentation.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915961/how-to-view-hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse-package-explorer

Comment: This might help noobs like me. I was searching for, "how to create nested packages in java". This answer perfectly explains that packages are unrelated in java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509219/nested-packages-in-java. So  in eclipse, just right click on src folder> New> Package. Then in name, type for example `utils.file` (assuming u have created `utils` package and want to nest `file` under it)

Answer (score 67):

Open the view menu in Package Explorer. There you can change **Package Presentation** from *Flat* to *Hierarchical*. I guess this is what you're looking for.