# Package presentation in Java EE perspective in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem when switching to my Java EE perspective in eclipse indigo.

In my Java perspective I have this layout:

[image: Non-collapsed package layout]

But when I switch to Java EE perspective I get this:

[image: Collapsed package layout]

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553425/is-there-a-way-to-nest-packages-in-eclipses-package-explorer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915961/how-to-view-hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse-package-explorer) unsuccessfully. I want to have the first layout in the Java EE perspective. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my settings in eclipse 4.2 which result in the layout you want:

```
- folder presentation: grouped
- package presentation: flat
```

Comment: I can find package presentation, but where is folder presentation??

Comment: You need to select the project for the folder presentation. Actually it works only with the package presentation as show by Flashpix. EDIT: Looks like you are using the spring toolsuite instead of eclipse. Similar problem reported here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?96485-Odd-behavior-with-hierarchical-package-presentation

Comment: that is true, I installed STS, could this be the matter?

Comment: I would think so. Just installed a clean eclipse indigo, imported a project and the presentation works. I suggest u try it to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

Package presentation can be found here :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can switch this using the "Package Presentation -> Flat" from the drop down menu in the project explorer.

[image: Package Presentation Snap]

Answer (score 1):

You can also import your project by using "import existing maven projects" .  It will then configure the folders to be flat.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers do not really solve the real problem that most noobs experience in Eclipse. So I thought I would add an answer to this question since the questioner resolved to reinstalling eclipse which is not necessary nor a viable solution. The real issue is that when you created or rather imported this project, you picked the option to create a `Project` in eclipse, not a `Java Project`. If you pick `Project`, it creates it as a filesystem looking directory structure similar to what you see in windows explorer. To fix this, just re-import your project from the workspace as a **"Java Project"** and you can change the package structure as flat or hierarchical as per your viewing pleasure.. Hope this helps.