# Maven - Wrong folder structure

Tags: maven

I have checked in one of my projects to GIT repo. When i cloned it from GIT, imported the project to eclipse and converted the project to Maven Project, the folder structure of maven seems to be a bit different

[image]

This should have been src/main/java, src/test/java, src/test/respurces folder structures and com.vod... as package.

I have tried maven>update project, project>clean, maven>clean, eclipse::clean, eclipse::eclipse. But this project structure does not seem to go off.

Any possible solutions for this please?

After importing the project as eclipse general project, below is the structure.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772969/package-presentation-in-java-ee-perspective-in-eclipse

Comment: @ppasler I already have the project presentation as flat. I have other maven projects in this same workspace whose structure is correct. I am facing issue only with this specific project.

Comment: It can be that you created one physical "main.java.com.vod.main" directory, instead of 5 (main/java/com/vod/main). And you should try to keep package names all lowercase.

Comment: @Tome please refer to edited question. All of them is not created as a single dirs

Comment: Are you using m2e in Eclipse? If not install it and use it to import Maven projects in Eclipse...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical problem due to the lack of Eclipse metadata files in the GIT repository.

How to solve it:

Open the project's contextual menu > Java Build Path > Configure Build Path > Source. Drop off folder `src` and set as folder sources just these:

- `src\main\java`
- `src\main\resources`
- `src\test\java`
- `src\test\resources`

This will save some metadata to the `.classpath` file.

Also, you should ensure that this was set as a Maven project: Open the project's contextual menu > Configure. If there is the `Convert to Maven` command, execute it (if not, it *is* already a Maven project). This might save some metadata to the `.project` file.

Then, be sure to check in the Eclipse metadata files (`.classpath`, `.project` and `.settings` folder) to GIT. And, in order for this project can be safely shared to other developers, be sure **not to enter absolute paths** in the java build path, nor other system-dependant constraints.

Comment: You should not checkin metadata files of Eclipse into Git cause by using the correct import functionality related to Eclipse M2E those files will automatically created....And then they are correct.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have learnt that, in practice, you save much trouble by publishing the metadata files in the control version system. What's wrong with it?