# Can I use packages without making all of the methods/ attributes public?

Tags: java, oop, package, visibility

I have a project with about 10 classes. I moved some classes to a package for clarity. Is there a safe way to connect between classes without data leaks? -using public is dangerous because anyone can change it.

After I moved some classes to a separate package, every method/ attribute I used has to be public/ have a getter. Getters of reference fields can make problems, as well as putting everything on 'public' visibility.

e.g. I have Handler class (not in the character package). Here, the Player class uses the handler's list of characters.

```
public class Handler {
    LinkedList<GameObject> objects = new LinkedList<>();
    ...
}

package player;
...
public class Player extends GameObject{
    ...
    private void collision() {
        for (GameObject tempObj : handler.objects) {
            ...             
        }

    }
...
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean data leaks, or that your code becomes uneasy to read (as in that you have access to too man methods)? If the second part, please read the following documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

This page tells about access control and how to use access modifiers.

Comment: I meant data leaks, for example if objects was public, someone could just use objects.clear(). btw please rethink about down voting- its quite hard to learn how to post a question, and without credit you can even add images.

Comment: Removed the downvote, now your question is more clear and I think that the answer given can help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to connect between classes without data leaks?

This is exactly what visibility modifiers are for!
Make everything private as default and "unprivate" as you go:

- Getters and (maybe) Setters for specific fields (Sometimes it might not be wise to make a value "setable", instead set it through your constructor)
- Divide and Conquer / Split it up: write small  visible (might be public, might be package-visible) methods which call private methods containing the logic

Using a good IDE will be helpful as it will recommend changing unnessecary public visibility to lower visibility. I use IntelliJ - it even lets you define a default visibility for generated methods.

Sharing data between two different instances / classes / things in general is dangerous and you cannot assert that data might not leak, but you can atleast make sure that your data is as protected as possible

Hopefully this answered you question :)

Comment: There is no safer way of doing that? The visibility modifiers don't do much if you are forced to have public all the time. You can use private field and public getters, but (correct me if I'm wrong) the data can still be manipulated if it's a reference field.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only content you can access outside of a package in java is the one tagged as public. I don't think there are any rules like special access to nested package (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509219/nested-packages-in-java) ). 
I don't know how much you want to protect your classes, but maybe you can add some kind of authentification/code to be able to use those public methods (or at least at the initialistaion).