# How to import a class that i wrote in java

Tags: java, class

So there is a folder in which there is the main.java file and a folder in which is a class,
how to import the class in main from the folder?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct folder import can't be achieved in java.

Following can be done

1. Package the other java class as jar
2. Include that jar in classpath of main program
3. Import the other java class in main program

Answer (score 3):

Given your question, I'm assuming that you're a beginner. Here are the steps to follow for Eclipse IDE:

1. Under the class (which you want to import) go to: File -> Export -> Java -> Jar file.
2. Choose the resources to export and select a destination for the jar file.
3. In the project where you want to import the file, go to: Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar -> Choose the jar file.
4. In the class where you need to use the file, write: import com.xxx.yyyy; (Package name).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the following:

- LibA.Package1

  - SomeClass.class
- LibA.Package2

  - Main.java

In your main file, you will need to use the full import path in the `Main.java`

```java
import LibA.Folder1.SomeClass
```

[See the following question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509219/nested-packages-in-java)