# How can I view packages as folder structure in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

In eclipse, I would like to see packages as a folder structure rather than the flattened look provided by the `Package Explorer` default settings, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Whats a subpackage? You can highlight an existing package and select the new package icon on the run bar, in order to have it pre-populate the existing packages name.

Comment: @jahroy I understand that you are off-put by the OP's claim to having searched for an answer, but I think a down vote is enough. Why not just answer? Or do your own research and find the duplicate.

Comment: @jahroy None of the things anyone is suggesting is actually creating a subpackage, I've tried it all already.  I'm wanting to have the packages be folders that I put other packages in, but I've tried many methods.  I've tried the ones on this page already.  Before you downgrade a question, how about you look into what it's actually asking?  Either my version of Eclipse is screwed up, or you people are misguided by what I'm asking.

Comment: Before asking a question, maybe you should determine if your question is valid.  I don't think you understand packages.

Comment: @jahroy I understand that in the default Java library there are sub-packages (Example: superPackage.subPackage.anotherSub.class).  And I found it rather reasonable to assume that Eclipse would have a convenient way of visualizing this.

Comment: I apologize for that last comment.  At the time it was extremely unclear what you were after.  As always, it helps to add as much detail when asking a question ;-) When in doubt, thorough descriptions and/or screenshots always help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eclipse offers the `Navigator` view which will display your project in the way you are asking.  To open this view select `Window > Show View > Navigator`.

Comment: I've already tried all of these methods.  Either my version of Eclipse is wacko or nobody is understanding what I'm wanting to do:  I want to put a package INSIDE of another package.  I've tried everything on this page already and nobody has given me a method that I'm yet to try.  It HAS to be possible to put a package within another in the project explorer.

Comment: Oh, lol... what you are talking about is the way Eclipse visualizes the packages. You might say that a package inside another is a "sub-package" but it isn't. It is really just another package. Eclipse will show you every package without having to expand nodes on a tree because it is way more convenient. Think about it, what you are asking would have just one tree node in the typical project explorer called `com` and to find the packages everyone would have to expand `com` then `example` then `www` then `my-package`... see how this would be annoying?

Comment: This is all about _how things appear in the explorer_??? That has never been made clear... Maybe you can just explore packages using "_file view_" rather than "_project view_" (if such a thing exists in Eclipse).

Comment: @jahroy yes it is, I'm working on a large project and it's confusing / annoying to have to shift through so many packages, I would much prefer to be able to put some within another.

Comment: @Tim Bender I understand why you think this would be annoying, but I find it convenient.  Is there a way to change how Eclipse visualizes the packages?

Comment: Try `Window -> Show View -> Navigator`.  It will allow you to navigate your source files like they appear on disk.  I've always found this to be better than "_Project Explorer_" myself... It acutally helps you understand the way your project is structured on disk.  You will probably want to expand the _src_ folder to find your packages. (the comment by @Perception suggested this 15 minutes ago)

Comment: Yeah, `Navigator` will do the trick. I would wonder if certain parts of your application are not better suited as independent libraries to be imported as Jar files. Though I could imagine a problem like that with a particularly large web application.

Comment: I agree with @JavaOverlord - I find the _Navigator_ view to be better than the _Project Explorer_ view (at least when dealing with their counterparts in NetBeans).

Comment: Okay, I did a bunch of cleanup on this question to try to make it halfway decent.

Answer (score 14):

Select the first package in the package explorer. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>**N**</kbd> to open the new item context menu. Click "Package."

Make sure that the new package name is a sub-package of the original package. For example, if your original package is `com.example`, the new package might be `com.example.gui`.

---

**EDIT**: If you want to *see* the nested packages, [Eugene says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3916062/732016) that you can do this:

> Package Explorer / View Menu (Ctrl-F10) / Package Presentation... /
>   Hierarchical

Comment: I have tried this already and it did not work.  It appears on the same "level" as its parent package.

Comment: @MatthewPage - I think you are misunderstanding what a Java package is. If you want to see the packages in a hierarchical view, then use the Navigator view (Window->Show View->Navigator).

Comment: Your edit is what he needed i think.
The hierarchical package presentation solved the problem for me. I think it's the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Click on three dots on project explorer toolbar  -> Package representation -> select
Hierarchical

[Eclipse Image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTGqm.png