# How can I make eclipse look like IDEA for its package listings?

Tags: eclipse

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA for some time, and recently I've been using Eclipse Kepler for my Java needs. One thing is driving me crazy though and I'm hoping there is a quick fix:

How can I make eclipse look like IDEA for its package listings? I find the flat display a 
giant distraction and need to get it looking better.

Compare this in IDEA:

[image]

to this in eclipse:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915961/how-to-view-hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse-package-explorer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package Explorer / View Menu (Ctrl-F10) / Package Presentation... / Hierarchical

Answer (score 1):

There should be the standard view settings triangle somewhere in the package manager. Click it and go to "Package Presentation", and select "Hierarchical".