# How can we make nested packages like this in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

So this article i am following has this guy nesting packages like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeReG.png). How can I achieve the same result?

I tried to nest a package like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeReG.png) but I was unable to make it like the image.

Comment: what ide are you using ?

Comment: Can you give more details about how you tried to nest the packages?

Comment: Im using Eclipse @AlejandroGonzalez

Comment: I tried to right click new package under the package it doesnt let me @YağızCanAslan

Comment: This is just about how your IDE displays the package hierarchy. If you have a package "mypackage" and another package named "mypackage.whatever" then some IDEs will give you the option to display that as nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to type the sub packages with a '.'
So if we have a main package say 'com.main' and we wanted to make sure we wanted to create a sub package for that
we should write it as 'com.main.sub'

and to make sure we have it visually follow that, you can read this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25378808/20406462

Answer (score 0):

As @Sanjeevan is using Eclipse, here is a way to nest packages in Eclipse;

1. Right click the `root folder` of your desired "nested" package branch,
2. Select `New > Folder`,
3. Type a name for the package and click `finish` (in this example, the name of the first folder is `parent`),
4. Right click the `parent` folder.
5. Select `New > Folder`,
6. Type a name for the package and click `finish` (in this example, the name of the second folder is `child`),
7. You will see a folder named `parent.child`. This is your nested "package". When you create a new class under this folder, either `package parent.child;` will be added automatically to the top of your classes, or you must add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

The layout of the packages on disk is standardized, it's not something you can change, and it's the same whether you're using `javac`, IDEA, Eclipse, or anything else. They are always nested. What you're looking for is how to change they way they're shown to you.

Change the **Package Presentation** setting in the View to **Hierarchical**.

[image: The local menu of the Package Explorer, showing how to change the way packages are presented]