# Collapsing sub-packages from NetBeans or Eclipse in java project view

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

[image: Packages]
I have view like

```
 + controller
 + framework
 + model
 - view
    Calc.java
    Main.java
 + view.main
 + view.newpackage
```

But i want that sub backages are collapsed into main packages like:

```
 + controller
 + framework
 + model
 - view
    Calc.java
    Main.java
    + main
    + newpackage
```

or

```
 + controller
 + framework
 + model
 + view
```

Know anybody is it possible in Eclipse and/or NetBeans?
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view hierarchical package structure in Eclipse package explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915961/how-to-view-hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse-package-explorer)

Comment: Right click anywhere in the white space of the `Projects` tab, select `View Java Packages as` and select your option...

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I asked that i didn't found such info.

Comment: Thank you i found it: http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2011/06/hierarchy-view-in-project-panel-of.html

Comment: @MadProgrammer: You should have mentioned that you are referring to Netbeans.

Comment: @JoachimRohde Now you're just spoiling my fun ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, if it makes you feel better: you teached me something new, even though I'm using Netbeans since version 3.x :-)

Comment: @JoachimRohde I stumbled across it some time after they switched the views...never bothered using it as I like the current view...had to go scrounging for it to post the comment :P

Answer (score 6):

**For Netbeans** (by @MadProgrammer in the comments)

> Right click anywhere in the white space of the Projects tab, select
>   View Java Packages as and select your option

**For Eclipse** (by @Smutje in the comments)

[How to view hierarchical package structure in Eclipse package explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915961/how-to-view-hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse-package-explorer)