# Creating Packages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, bukkit

Essentially I am trying to figure out how to set-up my Eclipse to be how the JD-GUI is displaying information. (Pictures below)

**JDGUI**
[image: JDGUI]

**ECLIPSE PROJECT**
[image: ECLIPSE PROJECT]

When I try to create the package for "Disguise" under "Commands" it just renames the "Commands" package to "Commands.Disguise" How am I able to create the remaining packages such as Perks, Social, Staff, Xyme...

Please help, thank you!

Comment: It's creating subpackages correctly.  Eclipse just collapses redundant package hierarchies if there's nothing in any of the intermediate packages.  So when you see "Commands.Disgise", that's actually a package and its subpackage.  As soon as you create a second package under "Commands", it should break them out the way you expect.  Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915961/how-to-view-hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse-package-explorer) may be relevant.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you!